# Line length mark in Python files

Tags: vimrc

I'm new to Vim and I'm trying to include a line length marker, but only in Python files. As far as I know, this line length marker can be added to Vim by using `set colorcolumn=<number>` in the `.vimrc`. That code adds a column everywhere in Vim, like the Explorer. How can I restrict it only to Python files?

Answer (score 1):

I've already find out how this is. I had to use `autocmd FileType python setlocal colorcolumn=79`.